# Maven: include selected folder into jar

Tags: maven

I have the below folder structures inside the **src/main/resources** folder.
My requirement is to build jar only for the **com.test.rma** folder only. I want to exclude the other folders during build. I tried with the below pom.xml. Currently, it is including all the folders. How do I explicitly keep only selected folders for build?

```
src/main/resources
     com.test.rma/
        sample.txt
     com.test.uw/
        sample.txt
     com.test.uw/
        sample.txt
```

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>architecture-drools-services</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.org.uwrules</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>myorg-io-maven-hosted</id>
            <name>myorgio Repository</name>
            <url>https://nexus.myorgdigital.com/repository/myorg-io-maven-hosted/</url>                               
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
            <version>7.59.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.59.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>7.59.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
                <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.59.0.Final</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <resources>
                      <resource>
                         <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                         <includes>
                            <include>/com.test.rma/**</include>
                         </includes>
                      </resource>
                    </resources>                

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I believe your mistake is following: `<resources>` - it is not a `maven-jar-plugin` configuration, that is `maven-resources-plugin` configuration

Comment: Simplest solution is to remove those folders from your project you don't like to include...

Answer (score 0):

Able to find the solution. maven jar plugin is not required post changing to maven resources plugin able to achieve it.

```
    <build>
        <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>com.test.rma/*.txt</include>
                    </includes>
                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
    </build>
```

Comment: that is `maven-resources-plugin` configuration :)))

Comment: yes you are right